# Force multiple lines for the name tag

Tags: titles

I'm currently entering authors an a paper and I came across this problem:

[image]

As you can see there are multiple names on one line, though outside the page. I would like to get them on two lines. At the moment I'm using the `\name` tag. I tried separating the lines the sentence by adding two backslashes, but it did not help. (I get "! Missing } inserted." error.) I tried replacing the `\name` tag by `\author`, but it did not work.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{spconf,amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cite}

 \title{Title}


 \name{Name1$^{1}$, Name2$^{3}$, name3$^{3}$ name4 $^{1,2}$, name5,$^{2}$ name6 $^{2}$, name7$^{3}$}


% 
\maketitle 
% 

\begin{abstract}
```

I tried:

```
 \name{Name1$^{1}$, Name2$^{3}$, name3$^{3}$ name4\\ $^{1,2}$, name5,$^{2}$ name6 $^{2}$, name7$^{3}$}
```

But I get an error.

Comment: Might be an idea with a full minimal example. I've never seen `\name` used, so more info please

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've been doing so far.

Comment: And what exactly is `spconf`? That is not available in my distribution. I tend to use the `authblk` package to provide a better interface for specifying authors.

Comment: It is latex style file provided to me.

Comment: In the style file I found: "\def\name#1{\gdef\@name{{\em #1}\\}}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to this [spconf.sty](http://code.google.com/p/2012-spring-sp/source/browse/Project/doc/proposal/?r=cc8bd0eb23fe62509aa20c3649af57806988e9a4) file, getting author names on more than one line is slightly awkward. The macro `\name` is defined by

```
\def\name#1{\gdef\@name{{\em #1}\\}}
```

and in the definition of `\maketitle`, we find

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@name \\ \@address  
\end{tabular}\par} \end{center}
```

So, if you use

```
\name{A. N. Author, \\ A. N. Other Author}
```

then `TeX` gets upset when `\maketitle` is executed because the `\\` in `\name` ends up trying to split the group surrounding `\em` across two lines of a tabular. One way around this is to bypass `\name`; thus

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spconf}
\makeatletter
\def\@name{ \emph{A. N. Author},  \\ \emph{A. N. Other Author}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

but the publisher may not be happy about such skulduggery.

Comment: Ok that seems to put them on two lines. Though the addresses which are put in \address stick to the names and \vspace or \\ or \newline is not separating them.

Comment: It seems that `spconf` supports one or two authors, not more: there's a `\twoauthors` command for two, but nothing else.

Comment: True, though by using several names in the name tag, it is possible. And because of this solution, I am able to put the names on 2 lines. Though the addresses are glued to the names atm

Answer (score 4):

I came across this post while trying to resolve the same problem. I am posting an alternate way here that works very well with spconf.sty. If you add an additional variable `\secondlinename` in the `spconf.sty` file as follows, you can get around this issue:

```
\def\@maketitle{\newpage
\null
\vskip 2em \begin{center}
{\large \bf \@title \par} \vskip 1.5em {\large \lineskip .5em
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@name \\[-1em] \@secondlinename\\ \@address
 \end{tabular}\par} \end{center}
 \par
 \vskip 1.5em}

\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{\uppercase{#1}}}
\def\name#1{\gdef\@name{{\em #1}\\}}
\def\secondlinename#1{\gdef\@secondlinename{{\em #1}\\}}
\def\address#1{\gdef\@address{#1}}
\gdef\@title{\uppercase{title of paper}}
\gdef\@name{{\em Name of author}\\}
\gdef\@secondlinename{{\em Name of second line author}\\}
\gdef\@address{Address - Line 1 \\
               Address - Line 2 \\0
               Address - Line 3}
```

In the source code, then you can have multiple names as follows:

```
\title{Title}


\name{Name1$^{1}$, Name2$^{3}$, name3$^{3}$ name4 $^{1,2}$,,\thanks{This project has received funding from the XYZ}
}
\secondlinename{name5$^{2}$, name6 $^{2}$, and name7$^{3}$}
\address{$^1$ address1\\$^2$address2\\$^3$address3}


% 
\maketitle 
% 

\begin{abstract}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your plain author list is too long to fit on one line, and you find that the line-break command

```
\\
```

does not work in the

```
\name
```

block, try wrapping the name list in a

```
{tabular}
```

block, as below:

```
\name{\begin{tabular}{c}Name First, Name Second, Name Third, Name Fourth \\
Name Fifth, Name Sixth, Name Seventh, Name Eighth\end{tabular}}
```

This information comes from the official website of [ICASSP 2018](https://2018.ieeeicassp.org/Papers/PaperKit.html)